# Node.js server hanging on startup | Websocket connection failed

Tags: node.js, express, server-side

So I'm trying to host a web app using node.js express and my server.js seems to hang upon using `npm start`.  In my package.json file it calls `node server.js` and everything starts properly but my website won't deploy to the local host for me to view.  I have a feeling it is either something to do with the location of my `css/index.html` or it could be something with the way i create the request from the client side from `index.html`  I'm new to backend, so really out in the deep on this one.

```
//1.) create http server
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 2525;
const INDEX = '/public/index.html';
const express = require('express')



var server = express();
console.log(__dirname)
server.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
server.get('public/index.html', function(req, res, next) {
      res.sendFile(__dirname + INDEX);
  });
server.listen(PORT);


//2.) Create a websocket server

const { Server } = require('ws');
const wss = new Server({ server });


//3.) Handle connections

wss.on('connection', (ws) => {
  console.log('Client connected');
  ws.on('close', () => console.log('Client disconnected'));
});


//4.) Boradcast updates
setInterval(() => {
  wss.clients.forEach((client) => {
    client.send(new Date().toTimeString());
  });
}, 1000);
console.log('Server started at http://localhost:' + PORT);
```

This is my index.html below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
  <title>am i sheep</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>

  <div>
    <span>
      <h3> Am I Sheep<h3>
    </span>
  </div>

  <div>
  </div>
  <div>
        <input type="file" id="fileID" hidden></input>
        <label for='fileID'>select image</label>
  </div>

  <div>
    <h1 id='server-time'>current time</h1>
    <script>
    var HOST = location.origin.replace(/^http/, 'ws')
    var ws = new WebSocket(HOST);
    var el;

    ws.onmessage = function (event) {
      el = document.getElementById('server-time');
      el.innerHTML = 'Server time: ' + event.data;
    };
    </script>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

UPDATE:

So the issue that seems to be popping up now is
`WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:2525/' failed`
`var ws = new WebSocket(HOST);`
So the error is happening between the handshake between the client and server

Comment: Sounds simple enough, which ports are accessing that of which your site wants to use?

Comment: Sounds like environment setup issues, another application sharing ports or something else.

Comment: i specifically went through and checked which ports were in use and terminated the pid's using this port.  If i run it once it starts and hangs, but if i run the server then close and start it again it will create an error because the port is in use.  I'm mainly confused why the website wont be deployed to the localhost.  I even used start and end timers to check if each part of the server.js file worked and it seemed to all work but still nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `server.js`

```js
//1.) create http server
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 2525;
const INDEX = "/public/index.html";
const express = require("express");
const { createServer } = require("http");

const app = express();
const httpServer = createServer(app);

// Static files
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
app.get("/", function (req, res, next) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + INDEX);
});

//2.) Create a websocket server
const { Server } = require("ws");
const wss = new Server({ server: httpServer });

//3.) Handle connections
wss.on("connection", ws => {
  console.log("Client connected");
  ws.on("close", () => console.log("Client disconnected"));
});

//4.) Boradcast updates
setInterval(() => {
  wss.clients.forEach(client => {
    client.send(new Date().toTimeString());
  });
}, 1000);

httpServer.listen(PORT, () => console.log("Server started at http://localhost:" + PORT));
```

The `index.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
    <title>am i sheep</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>

    <div>
        <span>
            <h3> Am I Sheep<h3>
        </span>
    </div>

    <div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="file" id="fileID" hidden></input>
        <label for='fileID'>select image</label>
    </div>

    <div>
        <h1 id='server-time'>current time</h1>
        <script>
            var HOST = location.origin.replace(/^http/, 'ws')
            var ws = new WebSocket(HOST);
            var el;

            ws.onopen = function () {
                alert('Connection Open');
            };

            ws.onerror = function (error) {
                alert('Error');
            };

            ws.onmessage = function (event) {
                el = document.getElementById('server-time');
                el.innerHTML = 'Server time: ' + event.data;
            };
        </script>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: it was working initially, but i tried to modify my server.js code to use my custom style.css and thats when it stopped working.

Comment: so whenever i use ```npm start`` it will run the server.js file fine, but it wont display the index.html on the localhost:2525

Comment: So in which url you opened it in browser?

Comment: i tried to open it in my browser, but it would not load anything.  I am running my environment in ubuntu so i did all of my setup from command line and then went to check localhost:2525 and nothing would show up in the browser

Comment: `server.get('public/index.html', ...` please review this line in `server.js`? If you want to open it exactly on `localhost:2525/`, you need to edit this into `server.get('/', ...` .

Comment: So UPDATE: i tried again and the webapp is at least displaying properly when i open localhost:2525 however i get the error 

WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:2525/' failed

this is within my index.html

Comment: @MarkMiller I edited my answer, please check it. This works fine for me.

Comment: This worked!!! Thanks so much!